# adding record event button only works once

Tags: c#, class, events, button

- List item

Basically i am making a application that stores data about a file.
The user can add a file to the collection by pressing my create new button and then inputting data into my text fields, the user then click save which adds the record to my Collection my issue is that the first time they do this it works fine everything updates.On the second go the save button is un-responsive, ive been working on this all day so i may have missed something or im just under experienced either way.

```
    public void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addRecord();
    }


   private void addRecord()
    {

        var newImage = new ImagesInfo();

        newImage.FileName = fileNameTextBox.Text;
        newImage.Category = categoryComboBox.Text;
        newImage.Date = dateTakenTextBox.Text;

        newImage.Description = descriptionTextBox.Text;
        newImage.Comments = commentsTextBox.Text;

        images.Add(newImage);

        if (editCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = images;

        }

        imageSelectComboBox.DataSource = images;

    }
```

Like i said if this is simple fix i apologize, but many thanks everyone.

**FIXED**

public void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addRecord();
        }

```
    private void addRecord()
    {
        //Save new Picture button

        var newImage = new ImagesInfo();

        newImage.FileName = fileNameTextBox.Text;
        newImage.Category = categoryComboBox.Text;
        newImage.Date = dateTakenTextBox.Text;

        newImage.Description = descriptionTextBox.Text;
        newImage.Comments = commentsTextBox.Text;

        images.Add(newImage);//Images reference is the problem.




        if (editCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            var source = new BindingSource();

            source.DataSource = images;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;


        }

        imageSelectComboBox.DataSource = images;
```

}

Comment: When you say "unresponsive", do you mean that your `dataGridView1` and/or `imageSelectComboBox` do not update their items?

Comment: Looks fine to me. So the old/first values always stay and new ones don't get added?

Comment: Sorry guys my bad, clouded thoughts, i did not bind the datasource :/ edited my post with my fix :)